# Clear the navigation stack with MvvmCross 6.2.1 and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, mvvmcross

We need to clear the navigation stack when navigating to certain pages in our Xamarin.Forms app on Android and iOS.

There's an article by Greg Shackles [here](https://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-using-presentation-values/) which describes how to do it - but this is approaching 4 years old and is for an older version of MvvmCross.

Is there a recommended way to do this with MvvmCross 6.2.1? Or do we still need to extend the Presenters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but you can use the `NoHistory` parameter on the `MvxContentPagePresentation` attribute.

Here is an example:

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(NoHistory = true)]
public class TestPage : MvxContentPage<TestViewModel>
{

}
```

(You must put this attribute on the **page** you're navigating to.)

This clears the navigation stack on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I needed. Is there also a way to specify this at runtime, as well as 'statically' as an attribute on the page?

Comment: Good to hear! I don't think its possible to do this at runtime (I checked the source code for you and it doesn't seem to be in there).